# как сохранить id записи SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

есть 2 фрагмента: в первом фрагменте при нажатии на кнопку создается запись в таблице с некоторыми, заполненными полями, и во втором фрагменте, я хочу продолжить редактирование этой записи. где ошибка?

```
 DataBaseHelper db= new DataBaseHelper(getActivity());
    Order order = new Order("photo1","photo2",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    db.addApplicaions(order);
    ID=order.get_id();
```

потом передаю данные в другой фрагмент:

```
 bundle.putInt("id",ID);
    checkData.setArguments(bundle);
```

и во втором получаю их, но беда в том что здесь :`ID=order.get_id();` всегда значение 0, я так понимаю я не верно получаю id

Comment: Как именно вы получаете данные во втором фрагменте

Comment: покажите метод ```addApplicaions()```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ID, скорее всего, назначается у вас автоматически для каждой новой записи в БД. В созданном же вами экземпляре класса `Order` этой инфы нет, ибо он никак не связан с БД.
Вам надо его из метода `addApplication` его возвращать и присваивать переменной `ID`. В этом вам поможет [знание](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5409803/3212712) о том, что метод `insert` как раз и возвращает `id` записанной строки

```
long id = db.insert(...);
```

Comment: подскажите а как правильнее обновлять запись? то есть во 2 фрагменте, мне надо обновить 3 поле, я обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Сергей, задайте это отдельным вопросом. А так, вроде, вам надо получить объект данных из БД, изменить его, и записать обратно.